# split array column wise even if equal division cannot be made using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

There's a row-split array function called: `array_split` that does:

> Split an array into multiple sub-arrays of equal or near-equal size.
>   Does not raise an exception if an equal division cannot be made.

now, I want to have the exact same functionally of this `array_split` but to columns.

There's a numpy function: `hsplit` that does:

> Split array into multiple sub-arrays horizontally (column-wise).

but it returns an error if an equal division can't be reached.

How it can be done?

Comment: Use the axis parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just transpose your array and use the same function:

```
A = np.random.random((4,5))
print([x.T for x in np.array_split(A.T, 3)])
```